# Configuring mouse scroll wheel actions

Tags: mouse

How do I configure actions for scroll wheel events on mac?

Specifically I'm looking for a way to configure the scroll wheel to change workspaces when a modifier key is pressed.

(I know BetterTouchTool can be used to configure many actions even for a regular mouse. However, it cannot configure actions that would be triggered by scroll wheel.)

Comment: What mouse r we talking about?

Answer (score 1):

You might use a [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) like this with KeyRemap4MacBook:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <autogen>__ScrollWheelToKey__ ScrollWheel::UP, VK_CONTROL |
    ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__ScrollWheelToKey__ ScrollWheel::DOWN, VK_CONTROL |
    ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```